# C++ Vector Sort method fails to compile, returns expected expression

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, cmake, cgal

I'm starting to work with cgal and I have just downloaded some sample code to start practicing. The problem is that when I try to compile the code, it returns:

```
ConvexHull.cpp:275:40: error: expected expression
sort(points.begin(), points.end(), [p] (Point_2 a, Point_2 b) -> int {
                                  ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/exec.e.dir/ConvexHull.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/exec.e.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

When I take a look at the code, everything seems ok:

```
Point_2 p = *(polygon.bottom_vertex());

sort(points.begin(), points.end(), [p] (Point_2 a, Point_2 b) -> int {
    Vector_2 v1(a, p);
    Vector_2 v2(b, p);
    
    return v1.direction() <= v2.direction();
});
```

Is this really wrong ?
Am I using the wrong compiler (It's using by default `Clang 3.1.0`) ? Did I miss anything ?

Any help is greatly appreciated

By the way: I'm using OSX Lion to develop, and the only thing I've installed is cgal(using homebrew) and its dependencies. To compile I run:

```
cd path/to/folder
cgal_create_CMakeLists -c Qt4:Core:GMP:MPFR:Boost -s exec.e
cmake -DCGAL_DIR=$HOME/CGAL-4.2 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
make
```

#### EDIT

I managed to install gcc-4.8 and g++-4.8 using homebrew. Than I ran the cmake command like this:

```
cmake -DCGAL_DIR=$HOME/CGAL-4.2 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-4.8 -DCMAKE_CC_COMPILER=gcc-4.8
```

Didn't even need to specify the `c++11` flag. It generated the executable file, but when I run it using `./exec.e` it segfaults `Segmentation fault: 11`. I am very frustrated at how hard this is turning out to be.

#### EDIT 2

I gave up using the MacOS. I was able to easily compile and run every required library and `CGAL`on a linux using `GCC-4.7`.

Comment: Make sure you're using `-std=c++11`.

Comment: I think you have to use `-std=c++11` option when compiling your code.

Comment: Hi @chris and @Nawaz. Thank you for your comments. I`ve tried using the methods described in [here](http://pageant.ghulbus.eu/?p=664) but it still throws me the same error. How would you guys use `-std=c+11` ? Just add this flag to the Makefile ?

Comment: Yeah, wherever your build command is, it needs to go in there and replace any of the related options for older versions.

Comment: Where have you downloaded that piece of code? I thought that CGAL examples were still using exclusively C++03.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code example that you showed has a C++11 language feature called [lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11).  Most compiler do not run in C++11 mode by default. To explicitly let them do so, put inside your `CMakeLists.txt`

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

and regenerate, rebuild and rerun everything to get your program to work correctly.

Comment: There is currently a [feature request](http://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=13842) targeted for CMake 2.8.12 to introduce a compiler-agnostic way of enabling C++11 support.

Comment: @ComicSansMS that's pretty nice!

Comment: I am convinced you are correct in your answer, but believe it or not the Clang compiler segfaulted when I added the flag. I am marking your answer as correct, and I'll search for another compiler option

Comment: @Luke the Clang 3.1 docs say `std=c++11`, if you happen to use an older version, you could try `std=c++0x` (also for gcc < 4.7).